# Powershell, Counting string ocurrences in a text file

Tags: string, powershell

I got a text file with the following layout,

```
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Ipsum user:john
Lorem Ipsum user:peter
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum user:george
Lorem Ipsum user:john
Lorem Ipsum  vLorem Ipsum user:george
Lorem Ipsum user:john
```

I must develop a script on Powershell V2 to count the occurrences and build a CSV with the following content,

```
john,3
george,2
peter,1
```

I was planning to loop thru the file saving each user in an array and then use get-content and a pattern to count the ocurrences, for example:

```
#assumming i was able to fill the array in some way :)
$users =@('john','peter', 'george')
for each ($user in $users)
{
     $count = get-content .\myfile.txt | select-string -pattern "user:$user"
     write-host $count
}
#save the CSV
```

Does it makes sense? I'm ear-opened to your hints and tips. Knowing the power of Powershell I'm pretty user there is a better approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current approach you will be reading the file from disk once for every user.  It might be better to scan the file once, and collect all users in a single pass.

It sounds like you don't have the list of users ahead of time, you basically need to scan for strings like `user:<username here>` and keep a running tally of the different usernames you find.

Here's a function that should do the basic job:

```
function GetUserCounts($fileName)
{
  $userCounts = @{}

  switch -regex -file $fileName
  {
    '\buser:([a-zA-Z]+)\b' {
       $userName = $matches[1]
       $userCounts[$userName] = [int]$userCounts[$userName] + 1
    }
  }

  $userCounts.GetEnumerator() | select Name,Value
}
```

That Then you can create a CSV like this:

```
PS> GetUserCounts .\myfile.txt | Export-Csv .\counts.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using the `Group-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-Content lorem.txt | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '^.+user:(.+)$','$1' } | 
Group-Object -NoElement
```