# Counting occurrences of a Regex and outputting to CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to use Powershell with a Regex pattern what will count the occurrences of that pattern in a text file. The occurrence could be repeated on a line or over multiple lines.

The output must be a Histogram of occurrence with the count.

Using [Powershell, Counting string ocurrences in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997777/powershell-counting-string-ocurrences-in-a-text-file) I was able to get this to work but realized it only works on a per line basis (eg when a match is found a It counts 1 but this is incorrect if there are multiple occurrences on the line)

Source might look like this

```
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Ipsum user:john
Lorem Ipsum user:peter
Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum user:george
Lorem Ipsum user:john user:john user: john user:johnasddaasd user:john
Lorem Ipsum  vLorem Ipsum user: george
Lorem Ipsum user:john
```

I currently have a script that is working on a per line basis - but not for the above example where there are multiple matches on a line

```
function GetUserCounts($fileName)
{
  $msgCounts = @{}

  switch -regex -file $fileName
  {
    '\buser:([a-zA-Z]+)\b' {
       $msgType = $matches[1]
       $msgCounts[$msgType] = [int]$msgCounts[$msgType] + 1
    }
  }

  $msgCounts.GetEnumerator() | select Name,Value
}

$currentDate = (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

$inputFile=$args[0]

GetUserCounts $inputFile | Export-Csv .\counts.csv -NoTypeInformation

import-csv .\counts.csv |
Select-Object *,@{Name='Filename';Expression={$inputFile}},@{Name='Rundate';Expression={$currentDate}} | 
export-csv msgCounts.csv -NoTypeInformation
Remove-Item .\counts.csv
```

Can someone help me get this example working for anywhere in the text file?

**UPDATE**
Output would look like

```
Name , Count
john, 6
peter, 1
george, 2
```

Comment: you probably need to use multiline switch for regex, and feed entire file into it

Comment: I was thinking along those lines but I think the logic is wrong in the script as it is using a switch to find the string and when it does it increments by one - not looking at the whole line

Comment: Then don't use a `switch` :-)

Comment: Exactly sir :) I'm new to Powershell

Comment: @Rob One question - why would `john` count 7 times? There are only 6 occurrences of `john` and 1 occurrence of `johnasddaasd`

Comment: @johnasddaasd - nice spot - editied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do another test inside each switch case. An easy way to do so is simply splitting the string and counting the result - 1:

```
switch -regex -file $fileName
{
  '\buser:([a-zA-Z]+)\b' {
    $msgType = $matches[1]
    $msgCount = ($_ -split [regex]::Escape($msgType)).Count - 1
    [int]$msgCounts[$msgType] += $msgCount
  }
}
```

---

Or use `Select-String` with the `-AllMatches` parameter switch and group on the captured groups from the resulting `Matches`:

```
(Select-String -Path .\test.txt '\buser:([a-zA-Z]+)\b' -AllMatches).Matches |ForEach-Object {
    $_.Groups[1].Value
} |Group -NoElement
```

Change the pattern to `'\buser:\s?([a-zA-Z]+)\b'` if you want to include the user names with a space in front

Comment: So this is great it matches all the occurrences but they are not grouped by the match is that hard to do ?

Comment: Regarding the first approach, instead of splitting you can use `[regex]::matches` that returns all matches.

Comment: Have been running the split for the last hour on my 200 mg file but no result yet - guess that's what you meant by unless you have a large file. Is there another option that would be faster?

Comment: @wOxxOm - I tried $msgCount = [regex]::matches.Count - but it still came back with just one match and not searching all occurrences - am I missing something

Comment: @Rob `[regex]::Matches($inputString,$pattern).Count` - although it still doesn't solve the problem of grouping by value

Comment: Im thinking the switch is the kicker here - is there another approach to load the file in as a string and for a regex all with a grouping there?

Comment: @Rob It is, I've modified the `Select-String` example to do what you're after

Comment: That's amazing - i'm so sorry I couldn't work this out on my own

Comment: @Rob Don't be sorry, just keep coding and asking questions ;-)

Comment: Just to let you know - that was very fast on the 200meg file